# How to efficiently create an array with a define() list?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a list of items that I need to check against in SQL queries and defined a constant to be used in the queries:

```
define(ORG_CHART_VARS, "'first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname', 'title', 'oc_work_status', 'oc_branch', 'oc_dept_id', 'oc_dept_card', 'oc_dept_card_group', 'oc_dept_card_sub', 'oc_emp_rank', 'about_page_URL', 'description'");
```

I want to create an array with the list and tried `$allMetaKeys = array(str_replace("'", "", explode("', '", ORG_CHART_VARS)));` <s>which worked for all but the first and last items</s>.

I know I can use regex to parse it out, but I am guessing there is an entirely more efficient way of doing this that I am not seeing.

Both the string and the array need to contain the same items, and they might change in the future (which is why I want a single list rather than 2) but I don't care if the array comes first or the string, they just need to match (and work in loops and SQL queries)

Comment: When you define your ORG_CHART_VARS, you should put it in quotes. `define('ORG_CHART_VARS', ...);` otherwise it'll throw a notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I'd question the decision to store a string list of values that like in a constant. It would be ideal to work with a data structure, like an array.

Having said that, your current code does appear to work for me, and includes the first and last items. However it does have an extra array level in there: https://3v4l.org/k9qQO

Assuming you really need to use a constant, you have a couple options:

### PHP 5.6+

If you are using PHP 5.6, you can actually store an array in a constant!

```
define('ORG_CHART_VARS', ['first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname', 'title', 'oc_work_status', 'oc_branch', 'oc_dept_id', 'oc_dept_card', 'oc_dept_card_group', 'oc_dept_card_sub', 'oc_emp_rank', 'about_page_URL', 'description']);
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/qQojT

It would be quite easy to use this array in your SQL queries with little modification. Just use `implode` when building your query.

```
$vars = "'" . implode("', '", ORG_CHART_VARS) . "'";
$query = "SELECT foo FROM table WHERE bar IN ($vars)";
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/GtFmv

### PHP <5.6

Otherwise, if you stick with your existing constant, you can improve your parsing code slightly.

If you flip your `str_replace` and `explode` you get a single-dimension array, with all your items:

```
$allMetaKeys = explode(", ", str_replace("'","", ORG_CHART_VARS));
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/2CvFQ

Comment: dammit! You are right, it wasn't the parsing that I was having trouble with, it was the extra array that was getting added. I do like swapping the `str_replace` and the `explode`, but is this the most efficient way of doing this?

As for the "String and an array" issue, it is for a SQL query:
` $query = "SELECT $foo FROM "TABLE." WHERE $bar IN (".VARS.")"; `, I wouldn't be against using a loop to build that string though.

Comment: @BillyNair Sure, I understand. But if you store an array, you have more flexibility. Your query just needs to `implode` that array, which I would say is preferable. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @BillyNair Most efficient way to split up a string in to an array, and remove the single quotes from around each piece of data? Yes I believe it is. =) Unless you change how you store the list in the first place, I believe this is your best option.

Comment: HHHMMMmmm... that implode option, I will look into that. it might be the missing link

Comment: @BillyNair just updated my answer with an example query

Comment: The question was about a more efficient way to share the same content in an array and in a string, and setting up an array then use the implode option was pretty dang efficient. I got rid of the define list and for the SQL wrote `AND foo IN ('".implode('\', \'', $allMetaKeys)."')";`

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward explode will work!

Note I have defined `ORG_CHART_VARS` correctly in quotes! I assume you are developing with `display_errors` turned off, so can I suggest you add these 2 lines of code at the top of all the script while you debug them

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define( 'ORG_CHART_VARS', "'first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname', 'title', 'oc_work_status', 'oc_branch', 'oc_dept_id', 'oc_dept_card', 'oc_dept_card_group', 'oc_dept_card_sub', 'oc_emp_rank', 'about_page_URL', 'description'");

$ar = explode(',', ORG_CHART_VARS);

print_r($ar);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'first_name'
    [1] =>  'last_name'
    [2] =>  'nickname'
    [3] =>  'title'
    [4] =>  'oc_work_status'
    [5] =>  'oc_branch'
    [6] =>  'oc_dept_id'
    [7] =>  'oc_dept_card'
    [8] =>  'oc_dept_card_group'
    [9] =>  'oc_dept_card_sub'
    [10] =>  'oc_emp_rank'
    [11] =>  'about_page_URL'
    [12] =>  'description'
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I did a "Double-Click & Drag" rather than a "Select, CTRL+C, CTRL+V" so the quotes weren't included. The code I was talking about (and strikethrough) was a previous code, that I thought was still a problem, and the problem really was in a foreach() where the value of "Array" is getting added somewhere.

Comment: @IlyasMimouni additional information which will always help the OP is always welcomed in an answer.